# Dereferencing variables in awk

Tags: variables, awk, dereference

Why doesn't this work?

```
x=5
$ ls -l | awk '{print $(($x))}'
```

should print field 5 of ls -l command, right?

Comment: awk is not shell, just like C is not shell. You should not expect to use shell variables or language constructs within an awk program any more than you'd expect to use them in a C program.

Answer (score 3):

The only ways you **should** pass in the value of shell variable to `awk` are the following

```
$ x=5

$ ls -l | awk -v x="$x" '{print $x}'

$ ls -l | awk '{print $x}' x="$x"
```

The main difference between these two methods is that by using `-v` the value of `x` is set in the `BEGIN` block whilst the second method the value would not be set. All other methods with quoting tricks or escaping **should not** be used unless you like headaches.

---

However you **don't** want to being parsing `ls` at all, the command you really want is:

```
stat --printf="%s\n" *
```

Assuming the fifth column of your `ls` is the same as mine, this will display all the file sizes in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

You could access the shell variable something similar to these;

The first way is not suggested!

```
x=5
ls -l | awk '{print $'$x'}'
```

or assigning the value x to the variable shellVar, before execution of the program begins

```
x=5
ls -l | awk -v shellVar="$x" '{print $shellVar}'
```

or using an array containing the values of the current environment

```
export x=5
ls -l | awk '{print $ENVIRON["x"]}'
```

Comment: Never do the first of the above or you will get nasty surprises for various contents of the variable "x". See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for a discussion of all the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

That's a shell variable, which is not expanded by the shell in single quotes.  The reason we put awk scripts in single quotes is precisely to prevent the shell from interpreting things meant for awk's benefit and screwing things up, but sometimes you want the shell to interpret part of it.

For something like this, I prefer to pass the value in as an awk variable:

```
ls -l | awk -v "x=$x" '{print $x}'
```

but you could do any number of other ways. For instance, this:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $'$x'}'
```

which should really be this:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $'"$x"'}'
```

alternatively, this:

```
ls -l | awk "{print \$$x}"
```

Comment: Only the first one above is close to being a valid option (should be `-v x="$x"`, don't do the rest. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for a discussion of all the alternatives.

Comment: Close? `-v x="$x"` and `-v "x=$x"` are completely indistinguishable by `awk`, which receives exactly the same argument strings from the shell in each case.  I could also have used `-'v' "x"'='"$x"` or any of a large number of other combinations.

Comment: It's misleading as `-v "x=$x"` looks like you're passing a string `"x=$x"` to the program to set the variable indicated by -v like the way -F "x=$x" would set the variable FS to the string "x=$x", while `-v x="$x"` is very clearly assigning the value of `"$x"` to the variable `x`. You're right you could have used any of those other combinations or more and they would also have obfuscated your code. Just keep it clear and simple: `variable="value"`.

Comment: Fair enough. I have no horse in the race of Awk style, and we're getting into too much for comments on SO anyway. I'm looking at it purely from a shell perspective, in which I find `x="$x"` more misleading; it looks like a shell assignment, when it's not (although it would be interpreted as one under `set -o keyword`, but I don't know anyone who runs with that option set). I just find it clearer to put grouping quotes all the way at the outside of the word being grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ls -l | awk '{print $'$x'}'
```

Comment: Never do that. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for a discussion of all the alternatives.